# 32 Bit Integer Mask

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, mask, bitwise-operators

I'm finishing up some CSE homework and I have a quick question about declaring integers of larger bit sizes. My task is to implement a function that returns 1 if any odd bit of x is 1 (assuming size of x is 32 bits) and returns 0 otherwise.

Am I allowed to declare an integer with the bit value:

10101010101010101010101010101010

If so, are there any problems that could arise from this?
If not, why not?? What alternatives do I have?

My function:

```
int any_odd_one(unsigned x)
{
    int mask = 10101010101010101010101010101010
    if(x & mask)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

-Matt

Comment: Use hex - `0xaaaaaaaa`?

Comment: Use `unsigned int` as the type for `mask`.  Using `int` is asking for trouble.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=0b10101010101010101010101010101010+in+hex) was my standard base converter in school

Comment: you need the "0b" prefix to the binary

Comment: @mikhailvs and a compiler that eats that nonstandard `0xbadf00d`.

Comment: If your assignment allows it ... and if the assignment assumes 32 bits (or lower) ... then a mask is definitely the way to go.  Your mask happens to be incorrect: I'd specify "unsigned long" (not "int"), and I'd specify "0xaaaaaaaa".  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 better `uint32_t` if you have C99.

Comment: `6 & 0xaaaaaaaa = 2` and `0xaaaaaaaa & 5 = 0` is this what you want ?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Could you explain why a signed int is asking for trouble?

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 In C, unsigned integers can only be represented in binary, whereas signed integers can be represented in any of: 2's complement, 1's complement or sign-magnitude. The bitwise operations reveal the details of the representation, for instance when `x` has type `int`, `x&(-1)` will not do what you are used to if the representation is sign-magnitude. This is largely theoretical nowadays as 99.99% of architectures use 2' complement, but the left shift operation is also UB for a negative first operand, originally because the representation of negative values can vary.

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 In short, if some integers are viewed as vectors of bits, it is safer to use an unsigned integer type to store these, and while on this topic, remember to make sure that `e` has already the intended width before computing `~ e`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use binary literals in C. Instead, use hexadecimal or octal notation.

In your case, you'd use `unsigned mask = 0xaaaaaaaa` since `10101010...` is `0xaaaaaaaa` when expressed in hexadecimal (each `1010` is `a` in hex).

Comment: Isn't that possible to keep binary using 0b10101010101010101010101010101010 in c programming?

Comment: GCC supports binary literals in C as a *GNU extension*, but they aren't standard C. C++14 standardized binary literals, but they aren't in any standard of C yet AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

It is more fun to implement this as `return !!(x&-1u/3*2);`.

In addition to the integer width stated in the problem, it works for any even number of bits in the `unsigned` type.

Comment: why do you use `!` 2 times ?

Comment: !! coerces to a 1 or 0 for non-0 and 0 respectively, which is usually unnecessary in C