# How many options can I include in a bit mask?

Tags: c++

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095354/32-bit-integer-mask) it was pointed out that:

> Using int [for bit mask] is asking for trouble

I have been using an `unsigned char` to store bitmask flags, but it occurs to me that I will hit low limit since a char is only a byte, thus 8 bits, thus only 8 options in my mask?

```
enum options{
 k1=1<<0,
 k2=1<<1,
  .... through to k8
 }

 unsigned char myOption=k2;
```

Do I simply need to make `myOption` an `int` or some other type for example if I wish it to store more than 8 possible options (and combinations of options, of course, hence why I am using the bit mask in the first place)? What's the best type?

Comment: Store it in an int and you have 32 bit options.. Doing this now in an old application. Use unsigned int.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` bits, actually. `sizeof(Type) * CHAR_BIT` will tell you how many you have for any type.

Comment: `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc,. should suffice.

Comment: Make myOption an unsigned int

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240707/enum-vs-macro-states-c

Comment: In the place where someone said `Using int is asking for trouble`, he also suggested using `unsigned int` - so your question is already answered there.

Comment: unsigned int should suffice unless you want to try using unsigned long long.

Comment: "What's the best type?" - `options myOption = k2;`... O_o

Comment: @TonyD that would prevent the setting of simultaneous flags in a single `myOption` which is the point of using the bit mask, right?

Comment: @Fellowshee: no, it doesn't prevent it at all - the Standard guarantees options can span a value made by bitwise-or of the specified enumerations. It's not particularly convenient though due to type conversions that kick in and required casting, but you can clean it up ala `option operator|(option lhs, option rhs) { return option(unsigned(lhs) | unsigned(rhs)); }` to aid usability....

Comment: @TonyD may I ask, if it "isn't particularly convenient," as you mention, then why you suggested it is the "best type" for my need?

Comment: @Fellowshee: because the compiler guarantees the necessary capacity, you can add user-defined operators as mentioned to control which operations are supported, you can have streaming functions that print the enumeration identifiers if wanted, and it's self-documenting when you see something in an `option` that the value relates to the enumerations, whereras some `int`-typed value needs to be tracked back to it's initialisation to understand how it's being used.  If you're prepared to lower yourself to macros you can auto-generate a deal of the supporting operators too.

Comment: @TonyD sounds like you are describing functionalities in `std::bitset` which would perhaps be a better alternative to re-inventing the wheel as I think you are suggesting.

Comment: @Fellowshee: that's completely missing the point of enums - that specific named enumerations are specified, and that each enum is a distinct type providing some type safety. Anyway, I'll leave it with you.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - `uint_least16_t`, etc. are a much better choice, since the exact-sized types won't exist on systems that don't have corresponding hardware types.

Comment: @PeteBecker Absolutely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

This defines types with fixed sizes that are not compiler specific.

int16_t = 16 bits

uint16_t = 16 bits unsigned

int32_t = 32 bits

If you need more than 64 flags you should consider the ::std::vector<> as Wayne Uroda suggested.

Comment: or more likely std::bitset

Comment: #0x499602D2 cstdint wasn't as widely supported the last time I checked.

Answer (score 3):

If you need an unknown number of 'bits' you could use something like the `std::vector<bool>` class, see here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/

This is a specialization of the vector class which can pack the bool values using bits, so it is more space efficient than an array of `bool`s (whether you need that extra efficiency is up to you).

Of course I don't know what your application is, there are many valid reasons for using bitfields. If you are simply storing a bunch of true and false values though, something like an array of bools or this vector of bools *might* be more easily maintained (it has downsides though of course, you can't test to see if say 3 bits are all set in one operation as you can with masking and bitfields, so it is application specific).

`vector<bool>` is somewhat controversial though, I think. See: http://howardhinnant.github.io/onvectorbool.html

Comment: ... and if you need a fixed number of bits and want to be sure you don't run out of space, you can use `std::bitset<N>`.

Comment: @templatetypedef and Wayne, as I noted in my question, I am setting _combinations_ of options, of which a bit mask is ripe for. A vector of bools wouldn't make this so easy. Does `bitset` support operations similar to `&` and `|` ?

Comment: @Fellowshee: Yep!  As you can see at this site (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), all of the bitwise operators are overloaded on `bitset`.  You can also use square brackets to select individual bits by index.  It's *super* useful for things like this.

Comment: On a vector of bools you can set combinations of options, you just have to set them one at a time... Like I said, it's application specific. I'm not 100% sure what you are doing so I'm sorry if my suggestion doesn't fit your use case :)

Comment: @templatetypedef that's beautiful. In fact, for bringing this to my attention, I think _you_ are beautiful.